# ¿Por qué mi textarea no agarra el placeholder que le pongo?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo una lista vacía predefinida:

```
<ul id="tool_list"></ul>
```

Una función que crea botones (usé div para tener mayor control de estilo y funciona sin problemas):

```js
function createButton(buttonId, buttonName) {
  return `<div class='button' id=${buttonId}>${buttonName}</div>`;
}
```

Y una función que añade ítems con un diseño predefinido:

```js
function addTool(label, labelId, editorData, buttons, resultAreaName) {
    
    var i = 0;
    var result = "";
    var buttonlist = "";
    while (i < buttons.length) {
        newButton = createButton(buttons[i][0], buttons[i][1]);
        buttonlist = buttonlist + newButton;
        i++;
    }
    document.getElementById("tool_list").innerHTML = document.getElementById("tool_list").innerHTML + '<li><p id=' + labelId + '>' + label + '</p><div class="subspaces"><textarea id=' + editorData[0] + ' placeholder=' + editorData[1] + ' rows=' + editorData[2] + '></textarea><div class="buttonlist">' + buttonlist +'</div><p id=' + resultAreaName + '>Results will appear here.</p></div></li>';
}
```

Y este comando para agregar una cierta
herramienta:

```js
addTool("Invertir texto:", "reversetextmod", ["reversetext", "Type your text here.", 4], [["processReversingText", "Procesar"]], "resultReverseArea");
```

El problema es que al ejecutar mi comando, el *placeholder* de mi `textarea` se corta a medias y en el código fuente me salen cosas como esta:

````html
<li><p id="reversetextmod">Invertir texto:</p><div class="subspaces"><textarea id="reversetext" placeholder="Type" your="" text="" here.="" rows="4"></textarea><div class="buttonlist"><div class="button" id="processReversingText">Procesar</div></div><p id="resultReverseArea">Results will appear here.</p></div></li>```
````

Unos **signos raros** donde va el *placeholder* de mi `textarea`. No he podido quitarlos. Desde ahí se *trunca* el funcionamiento y no me deja seguir de forma adecuada. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

NOTA: **NO ES OPCIÓN** USAR createElement, NO PUEDO PONERLE ID A LAS COSAS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Es porque tienes un error al crear los atributos. Si te das cuenta, no has colocado las dobles comillas (`"`) que son el estándar para envolver los valores de cualquier atributo HTML:

```html
<textarea id="valor" placeholder="valor" rows="valor"></textarea>
```

Tal como lo tienes ahora, no has respetado las comillas dobles, simplemente estás insertando el valor de `editorData[1]`:

```js
<textarea id=' + editorData[0] + ' placeholder=' + editorData[1] + ' rows=' + editorData[2] + '></textarea>
```

Podemos ver el comportamiento en el siguiente snippet:

```js
let placeholders = [
  'Esto es incorrecto',
  'Esto es correcto'
];

document.getElementById('mal').innerHTML += '<textarea placeholder=' + placeholders[0] + '></textarea>';

document.getElementById('bien').innerHTML += '<textarea placeholder="' + placeholders[1] + '"></textarea>';

document.getElementById('htmlMAL').innerText = document.getElementById('mal').innerHTML;

document.getElementById('htmlBIEN').innerText = document.getElementById('bien').innerHTML;
```

```html
<div id="mal"></div>
<pre id="htmlMAL"></pre>
<div id="bien"></div>
<pre id="htmlBIEN"></pre>
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es simple, agrega las comillas dobles de apertura y cierre para que el navegador sepa que el contenido de `editorData[i]` que será insertado en el HTML mediante Javascript, es efectivamente el valor del atributo *placeholder* de tu elemento `textarea`. No sólo debes añadir las dobles comillas en dicho atributo, sino en todos los atributos que estás generando de esta forma.

El código debería verse así:

```js
document.getElementById("tool_list").innerHTML += '<li><p id="' + labelId + '">' + label + '</p><div class="subspaces"><textarea id="' + editorData[0] + '" placeholder="' + editorData[1] + '" rows="' + editorData[2] + '"></textarea><div class="buttonlist">' + buttonlist +'</div><p id="' + resultAreaName + '">Results will appear here.</p></div></li>';
```

Otra solución es que utilices una [plantilla de cadena literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) para insertar los datos, por ejemplo:

```js
document.getElementById("tool_list").innerHTML += 
  `<li>
    <p id="${labelId}">${label}</p>
    <div class="subspaces">
      <textarea id="${editorData[0]}" placeholder="${editorData[1]}" rows="${editorData[2]}"></textarea>
      <div class="buttonlist">${buttonlist}</div>
      <p id="${resultAreaName}">Results will appear here.</p>
    </div>
  </li>`;
```

De esta forma se entiende un poco mejor los valores y el contenido de la cadena que estás añadiendo a tu elemento. Recuerda siempre revisar al [tabla de compatibilidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#compatibilidad_de_navegadores) de las cadenas literales antes de aplicarlas.

Espero que esto aclare tu duda y te ayude a resolver este y otros problemas similares.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Si, era eso  y otros errores de código. Ya funciona como debe ser y le puse window.onLoad para que mis addEventListener funcionen como debe ser. ¡Ten un buen día (o noche)!